# Trouble rendering box from index buffer with PyOpenGL

Tags: python, qt, opengl, numpy

I'm trying to work through the beginning of the OpenGL redbook for version 2.1 and translate what I learn to the PyOpenGL binding while using Qt for the windowing framework. For some reason though, I can't seem to get my call to `glDrawElements()` to actually draw anything to the screen. Here are the relevant functions I have so far.

```
def initializeGL(self):
    self.qglClearColor(QtGui.QColor(0,0,150))
    self.initGeometry()
    GL.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    self.buffers = GL.glGenBuffers(2)

def paintGL(self):
    GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    GL.glLoadIdentity()
    GL.glTranslate(0.0, 0.0, -50.0)
    GL.glScale(20.0, 20.0, 20.0)
    GL.glRotate(self.yRotDeg, 0.2, 1.0, 0.3)
    GL.glTranslate(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)

    VERTICES = 0
    INDICES = 1
    GL.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buffers[VERTICES])
    GL.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, len(self.cubeVtxArray), self.cubeVtxArray, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    offset = ctypes.c_void_p(0)
    GL.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, offset)
    #GL.glVertexPointerf(self.cubeVtxArray)
    GL.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    GL.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.buffers[INDICES])
    GL.glBufferData(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, len(self.cubeIdxArray), self.cubeIdxArray, GL.GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    GL.glDrawElements(GL.GL_QUADS, 24, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, offset)
    #GL.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_QUADS, 0, 24)

def initGeometry(self):
    self.cubeVtxArray = np.array(
            [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
             [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
             [1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
             [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
             [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
             [1.0, 0.0, 1.0],
             [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
             [0.0, 1.0, 1.0]], dtype=np.float32)
    self.cubeIdxArray = np.array([
            0, 1, 2, 3,
            3, 2, 6, 7,
            1, 0, 4, 5,
            2, 1, 5, 6,
            0, 3, 7, 4,
            7, 6, 5, 4], dtype=np.uint8)
```

When I run the program, it does clear the screen to the correct color, but the cube isn't drawn. Interestingly, if I try and render using the `glDrawArray()` function, it does render (although it doesn't look like a cube since it's rendering the indices). What might be going wrong here?

EDIT:
Here are a couple videos of the results of [glDrawElements()](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvwo6w9jz8pnnpt/opengl_app.mp4?dl=0) and [glDrawArrays()](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ozxef9hpp993bic/opengl_app1.mp4?dl=0).

EDIT2:
My problem (as user1118321 pointed out) was that I was passing an array length as the second parameter to `glBufferData()` where I should have been passing a size in bytes. The solution for python is:

1. `from OpenGL.arrays.arraydatatype import ArrayDatatype`
2. Use `ArrayDatatype.arrayByteCount(self.cubeVtxArray)` as the second parameter to `glBufferData()` (and similarly for any other buffers).

EDIT 3:
I'd actually like to make one more edit to this since I just ended up with another related problem from my calls to glBufferData(). I thought naively that I should also be able to use sys.getsizeof() in the same way as ArrayDatatype.arrayByteCount(). This is not the case though if your buffer data is a numpy array as I ended up using. sys.getsizeof() returns the wrong size and will inadvertently chop your array a bit. Goodbye three days of my life....

Comment: I don't understand the specifics of the python bindings, but I noticed that it says `np.ubyte` as the type of your index array, while you specify `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` as the index type in the argument for `glDrawElements()`. Isn't that a mismatch?

Comment: Shoot, sorry. I thought data types might be my problem so I was playing with those right before posing this. I fixed the code and it does render now but it's choppy and definitely doesn't resemble a cube even though the vertices and indices were pulled from a working cube program. I made a couple videos of the results I'm getting and edited question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that looks wrong to me is that you're sending the array size as the second argument to `glBufferData`. You probably need to send the number of bytes of the data as that argument. So it would be something like:

```
 len(self.cubeVtxArray) * numBytesPerElement
```

where `numBytesPerElement` would be 4 bytes per float times 3 floats per vertex = 12 bytes.

In Python, you can get the number of bytes in an array by doing the following:

1. from `OpenGL.arrays.arraydatatype import ArrayDatatype`
2. Use `ArrayDatatype.arrayByteCount(self.cubeVtxArray)` as the second parameter to `glBufferData()` (and similarly for any other buffers).

   And you'll need to do the same thing for `self.cubeIdxArray`, though the `numBytesPerElement` will be 1 in that case.

Comment: Wow, what an easy fix haha. Thank you. I'm accepting your answer but would you mind adding the python specifics to it in case anyone else runs into this trouble? I included the fix at the end of my question but it should really go in the answer.

Comment: Sure thing! I'll add it now.